# How to apply a right fold on a list using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to perform a right fold with a division operator and an initial value of 1 on a list [1, 2, 3, 4]. But I'm not getting the expected solution.

This is my code:

```
reduce(lambda a,b: a/b, [1,2,3,4], 1)
```

The solution is: 0.0416666; but the expected solution should be: 0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, or 0.5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please describe what you think the code should do exactly. Maybe try it with a classic function instead of a lambda to unravel it.

Comment: reduce does a full fold, if you want partial folds use `itertools.accumulate`? but I don't think that's what you want anyways, since you'll get `[1, 1/2, 1/6, 1/24]` instead of `[0, 1/8, 2/8, 3/8, 4/8]` like you say.

Comment: Why do you expect one of five possibilities? Which one is it? Is this a multiple-choice question and those are the answers and you don't know the answer?

Comment: Reduce is left fold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a *left* fold to me. With a *right* fold I do get 0.375:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: b / a, reversed([1, 2, 3, 4]), 1)
0.375
```

Ha, [Wikipedia's Fold article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#In_various_languages) even has a table that shows you how to do it in Python (and many other languages).